# Compare a column from two different sheets and return true/false

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need to compare a column from two different Excel sheets and return a value of true or false.

Answer (score 2):

Comparing the whole column:

```
=(Sheet1!A:A=Sheet2!A:A)
```

or comparing a cell in the two sheets:

```
=(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1)
```

This will put TRUE in the cell where the formula is, if the two columns or cells are the same, and FALSE if they're different.